# How do I Invoke Code Completion for JupyterLab Desktop?

Tags: jupyter-lab, code-completion

JupyterLab reports version 4.0.5
JupyterLab Desktop reports version 4.0.5-1

I am using the default environment.
I am using linux.

By code completion, I do not mean using the tab button on the keyboard.

I expect a list box to pop up as I type with a selection of choices.

There is no code completion item to select in Settings.

When I open a code console, there is no code completion for ipython.

The ipython console says Python 3.8.17, IPython 8.12

One problem with searching the web for a solution is that most "solutions" return references to jupyter notebook, even though I have tried to exclude that term. It has made my brain hurt.

Now, I do have access to another computer running JupyterLab Desktop. It is also a linux machine.
JupyterLab returns all the same version numbers - yet it has a code completion option under Settings.

And code completion works without requiring the use of tab.

This other computer I set up also. I cannot say if I did something different with each installation of JupyterLab Desktop, though.

All advice welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered, finally, how to access code completion.
In the View menu make sure that Extension Manager is ticked. Close the Settings tab. Re-open the Settings tab, and the Code Completion option entry is there.